# How can I make my borderless Window be the Key Window after launch?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am making a window without border or title, but after launch the window is not the key window with this code:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        window.styleMask = [.fullSizeContentView]
        window.backingType = .buffered            
        
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
        
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }
    
}

let nsApplication: NSApplication = NSApplication.shared
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
nsApplication.delegate = appDelegate
nsApplication.run()
```

The issue photo:

[image]

But it should be like:

[image]

I tried to solve the issue with `window.makeKey()` but it did not help also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular NSWindow is either borderless or titled.  As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/stylemask/1644698-borderless), borderless windows cannot become key or main unless you override the `canBecomeMain` and `canBecomeKey` properties.

You have two options.  If you want a true borderless window then subclass NSWindow and override the override the `canBecomeMain` and `canBecomeKey` properties:

```
class AlwaysKeyWindow : NSWindow {
    override var canBecomeMain: Bool { return true }
    override var canBecomeKey: Bool { return true }
}

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private lazy var window = AlwaysKeyWindow()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window.styleMask = [ .borderless ] // Same as styleMask = []
        // ... etc ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a normal window with a hidden/transparent title bar:

```
window.styleMask = [ .titled, fullSizeContentView ]
window.titleVisibility = .hidden
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

This will behave like a regular window (it will appear in the "Window" menu and use the standard window shadows and corner radius) but it will not draw its title bar.

Comment: Thanks, both ways are good for solving the issue!